# Is there any convenient iOS AR SDK available？

Tags: ios, sdk, augmented-reality

I want to do something like this:

With iPhone's camera and AR tech, I could stick one virtual paper to the desk in front of me in the real world and wherever I put my iPhone around that place I stick the paper and it still seems that the paper is on the original position where I've put it at first.

If I want to make it come true, what do I need? And what SDK is more suitable for me to use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at http://socialcompare.com/en/comparison/augmented-reality-sdks to see which AR SDK support iOS.  You can start by looking into ARToolkit, Metaio, String, Vuforia, and Wikitude.

Comment: Thank you for your advice. I had solved it with Vuforia long time ago though. It is an old question ^^.  However, the available SDKs you listed there are useful to me, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

This question is pretty old now. Is it still open? You can try out [Qualcomm Vuforia](http://www.qualcomm.com/solutions/augmented-reality)

Comment: vuforia is what you want.